# Custom SearchBar (iOS)

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Добрый день. Занимаюсь кастомизацией SearchBar под заказ. И наткнулся на проблему которую не могу решить. У кнопки "Cansel" -> "Отмена" есть какой-то shadow серого цвета, причем отключить я его не могу. Как я только не пробовал это делать.

```
cancelButton.titleLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor greenColor]; //Цвет для теста
cancelButton.titleLabel.layar.shadowColor = [UIColor greenColor]; 
cancelButton.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
cancelButton.titleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Ничего не помогает убрать этот эффект. [image]

[image]

Пробовал даже ложить UILable на button но безуспешно. Подскажите как это сделать !!!

Зарание спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне кажется это атрибуты текста попробуйте чтонить типа:

```
 NSDictionary *attributes =
[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
 [UIColor whiteColor], UITextAttributeTextColor,
 [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0], UITextAttributeTextShadowColor,
 [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0, 0)], UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset,
 [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12], UITextAttributeFont,
 nil];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil]
setTitleTextAttributes:attributes forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 [[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil]
setTitleTextAttributes:attributes forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

Comment: Я подобное пробовал, не помогло =(

Comment: Ладно я дома попробую.

Comment: Все я сделал! Спасибо!

Comment: от блин, ну ладно дома че нить другое поковыряю )

Answer (score 1):

Там обычная кнопка типа UIButton? Если да то у нее для titleLabel надо дергать не напрямую параметры, а через методы UIButton вида `- (void)setTitleShadowColor:(UIColor *)color forState:(UIControlState)state` т.к. иначе кнопка будет менять установленые вами свойства при измении состояния кнопки. Вы так пробовали делать?

Comment: У меня функция которая отлавливает любой вздох этой кнопки и при ее действии всегда заставляет ее применять параметры. Сейчас попробую с вашими методами! и отпишусь!

Comment: Не хочет...

Comment: А можете вытащить этот кусок и где-нибудь опубликовать? Я б тогда на коде глянул.